# Running IBM Data Studio 4.1.01 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, eclipse

I've successfully installed IBM Data Studio and its Web Console on Ubuntu 14.04, and the Web Console runs like a dream and I can connect to my DB2 databases fine. However, when I try and run the Data Studio application (eclipse) and click on any of the tasks located in there, I get the following error message :

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=160
/opt/IBM/DS4.1.0.1//jdk/jre/bin/javaw
-Xquickstart
-Xms40m
-Xmx1024m
-Xgcpolicy:gencon
-Xscmx96m
-Xshareclasses:name=IBMSDP_%u
-Xnolinenumbers
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M
-jar /opt/IBM/DS4.1.0.1//plugins org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash
-launcher /opt/IBM/DS4.1.0.1/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /opt/IBM/DS4.1.0.1//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807/eclipse_1502.so
-startup /opt/IBM/DS4.1.0.1//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-exitdata 550010
-install /opt/IBM/DS4.1.0.1
-product com.ibm.datastudio.consolidated.product.ide
-vm /opt/IBM/DS4.1.0.1//jdk/jre/bin/javaw
-vmargs
-Xquickstart
-Xms40m
-Xmx1024m
-Xgcpolicy:gencon
-Xscmx96m
-Xshareclasses:name=IBMSDP_%u
-Xnolinenumbers
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M
-jar /opt/IBM/DS4.1.0.1//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
```

Checked my Java version and its 1.7.0_51:

```
java version "1.7.0_51"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.6) (7u51-2.4.6-1ubuntu4)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: Solved it by adding a line to /opt/IBM/DS4.1.0.1/eclipse.ini

Comment: How were you able to connect to db2 in ubuntu. what would the host name be as we will be logged in as a different user

Answer (score 1):

Incase anyone else runs into this issue, I resolved it by adding the following line to /opt/IBM/DS4.1.0.1/eclipse.ini :

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
```

Cheers! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem with Rational Software Architect on Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit. 
the solution that worked for me was to edit the /opt/IBM/SDP/eclipse.ini and I added the following a vmargs as follows:

> `-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla`

That was enough for me on the other hand the below argument didn't work for me and was not enough.

> `-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath=/opt/xulrunner`